# C# New application stuck in loading when launched

Tags: c#

**Hello,**

I do not what happened, but, when I make new "Console Applications" in C# it works and I can make a debug version. However when I launch the .exe from the "Debug" folder the .exe doesn't show up, the console window doesn't appear and the .exe isn't shown under "task manager".

However when I taskkill it in CMD it can close it, however the C# cannot recompile it since it says its opened in another process. When I try to terminate it by using "taskkill /F /IM filename.exe" it says there is no running process.

Here is a screenshot in the "Debug" folder, my cursor is infinity having the circle of loading.
[image: Debug folder / Debug folder]

[image: C# program console error]

Comment: Close and reopen visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

Avast smart-scan was messing up my newly coded programs.